# How to centre cirtuitikz components vertically in a table

Tags: vertical-alignment, circuitikz

I need to make a table of electric circuit diagram components. The components are being drawn with `circuitikz`. Here is the code I have tried to use. `\renewcommand{arraystretch}{2.5}` is commented out here, which I used to try to get some vertical padding. The output generated by the code (both with and without the arraystretch setting) is shown below.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  too high &
             \begin{circuitikz}
               \draw (0,0) to [lamp] (2,0);
             \end{circuitikz} 
\\ \hline 
  this one is centred vertically   &
                                     \begin{circuitikz} 
                                       \draw (0,0) to [european resistor] (2,0);
                                     \end{circuitikz} 
\\ \hline
  but this on is too high &
                            \begin{circuitikz} 
                              \draw (0,0) to [empty diode] (2,0);
                            \end{circuitikz} 
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: with arraystretch]
[image: without arryastretch]

How can I create such a table in which the diagrams of the components are centred vertically and have some vertical padding within their repsective table cells (preferably without the need to adjust each diagram's position by hand)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

small modification of the [Phelype Oleinik's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134574/phelype-oleinik) answer. added is `cellspace` package for adding vertical space above and below cells' contents:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{array,cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}    % can be placed before "\begin{tabular}"
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\tikzset{baseline={([yshift=-0.5ex]current bounding box.center)}}% fixed position of current bounding box
    \begin{tabular}{|Sc|Sc|}
  \hline
too high
    &   \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [lamp] (2,0);
        \end{circuitikz}                \\
    \hline
this one is centred vertically
    &   \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [european resistor] (0,2);
        \end{circuitikz}                \\
    \hline
but this on is too high
    &   \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [empty diode,anchor=west] (2,0);
    \end{circuitikz}                    \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know of `cellspace`. Very neat :)

Comment: Many thanks. It's not clear to me why the resistor has rotated through 90 degrees. I am also unfamiliar with the `S` option to tabular, and I'm struggling to find a reference that explains it. Any hints?

Comment: resistor is rotate with purpose: to demonstrate that element can be tall and solution still works. if you not wish it in vertical direction, just change coordinates from `\draw (0,0) to [european resistor] (0,2);` to `\draw (0,0) to [european resistor] (2,0);`. `S` activate adding vertical space to cells in selected columns. if you omit it, additional vertical space will disappear. for more details about package `cellspace` read its documentation. it is part of your latex installation or find it by help of google (search for "cellspace latex").

Comment: Yes, I guessed why you *chose* to turn the resistor, but I just hadn't spotted *how*: even in your explanation in the comment it took me some effort to sport that the `2` and `0` were swapped. And `S` comes with `cellspace` which would explain why I wasn't finding it in the description of `tabular` etc. It's clear now. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is that Ti*k*Z aligns the base of the picture with the baseline of the text. You can change the baseline of the drawing with the `baseline option`:

> [image]

With `baseline=(current bounding box.center)` you align the baseline of the text with the center of the picture. To make it look more centered you can add an `yshift` to align the center of the picture width the center of the text. In my opinion `yshift=-.6ex` looks good.

You can put this setting in a `\tikzset` within a group. Once that group ends, the setting will be restored. If you put this setting inside a `\begin{table}` it will work.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

{%
\tikzset{baseline={([yshift=-.6ex]current bounding box.center)}}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  too high &
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [lamp] (2,0);
  \end{circuitikz}
\\ \hline 
  this one is centred vertically   &
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [european resistor] (2,0);
  \end{circuitikz}
\\ \hline
  but this on is too high &
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [empty diode,anchor=west] (2,0);
  \end{circuitikz}
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}%

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  too high &
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [lamp] (2,0);
  \end{circuitikz}
\\ \hline 
  this one is centred vertically   &
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [european resistor] (2,0);
  \end{circuitikz}
\\ \hline
  but this on is too high &
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [empty diode,anchor=west] (2,0);
  \end{circuitikz}
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

---

You may sat, then, "but the pictures in the second table are not centered!". Well, neither is the text! When you change `\arraystretch`, the text will not be centered and, as a consequence, the baseline will not change and the picture will not move.

But, if you really insist on it, you can make a linear relation between `\arraystretch` and a position that makes the picture centered. I advise *against* using this though:

> [image]

But people on the Internet tend to disagree with things, so yo use this scheme you have to change the `\arraystretch`, then use `\calcshift`, and then use `\tikzset{baseline={([yshift=\yshift]current bounding box.center)}}`. Note that the text is still at the usual position...

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\newdimen\yshift
\def\calcshift{\yshift\dimexpr-0.6ex-0.5\dimexpr\arraystretch ex-1ex\relax\relax}

\begin{document}

{%
\calcshift
\tikzset{baseline={([yshift=\yshift]current bounding box.center)}}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  too high &
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [lamp] (2,0);
  \end{circuitikz}
\\ \hline 
  this one is centred vertically   &
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [european resistor] (2,0);
  \end{circuitikz}
\\ \hline
  but this on is too high &
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [empty diode,anchor=west] (2,0);
  \end{circuitikz}
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
\calcshift
\tikzset{baseline={([yshift=\yshift]current bounding box.center)}}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  too high &
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [lamp] (2,0);
  \end{circuitikz}
\\ \hline 
  this one is centred vertically   &
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [european resistor] (2,0);
  \end{circuitikz}
\\ \hline
  but this on is too high &
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [empty diode,anchor=west] (2,0);
  \end{circuitikz}
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{5}
\calcshift
\tikzset{baseline={([yshift=\yshift]current bounding box.center)}}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  too high &
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [lamp] (2,0);
  \end{circuitikz}
\\ \hline 
  this one is centred vertically   &
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [european resistor] (2,0);
  \end{circuitikz}
\\ \hline
  but this on is too high &
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [empty diode,anchor=west] (2,0);
  \end{circuitikz}
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way of making `circuitikz` use `[baseline={([yshift=-.8ex] current bounding box.center)}]` by default, preferably **within a limited scope** (such as the current tabular). Better still, is there a way of using half of the value of arraystretch, rather than hard-wiring `.8ex`?

Comment: @jacg There you go. I would not use the second version though, it looks really off. If you use another method to vertically center the contents of the table, then the "hardwired" `0.6ex` will still work (depending on the font you're using this number may change, but will be constant within that font).